# How to use fcntl reading status of lock file?

Tags: python

I have a simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import fcntl
file = open("e", "w")
fcntl.lockf(file.fileno(),fcntl.LOCK_EX)
file.write("foo")
file.close()
```

How to know locked file or not ? ( Not waiting until file is unlocked )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what `fcntl.LOCK_NB` is for. For example:

```
import warnings
try:
    fcntl.flock(myfile, fcntl.LOCK_EX|fcntl.LOCK_NB)
except IOError:
    warnings.warn("can't immediately write-lock the file ($!), blocking ...")
    fcntl.flock(myfile, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
```

From [file access](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/fileaccess.html).